# Getting error while updating state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am updating the state of my application getting the error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I have react page on which i am fetching the data using flask as a backend (using fetch to call the restapi)
and then i am displaying the data in table and using Material-table. https://material-table.com/#/

On the table i have a option to edit the rows and update the values of the rows (there is option to edit only single line)
when the row is edited i am clicking on save button to save the data in backend.
The data is getting updated in backend and then on successful updating the value **i am again fetching the updated data**

i want to get rid of this step - to fetch data again after updating since the data is large around 200K records and it takes 2-3 minutes for rendering the data (i don't want the user to again again for 2-3 minutes every time they update the row. I have used pagination also but it didn't help me much since i have a option to search the columns and in case of pagination it will search only on the selected page)

So to get rid of the step to fetch data again from the database

i have performed the below steps
1) i know the index for which the value is changed let's say it is in indexChange
2) i know the new value let's say it is saved in variable newValue
3) the state this.state.data is array.
so i am looping over this array and when the array index is equals to indexchange i am updating the array value
4) and then updating the required state using this.setState({data: newState})

code is as follows

```
replaceStateObject(oldval, newval){
      var newState = this.state.data;
      var changedIndex = oldval['tableData']['id']
      newState.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
        if(index == changedIndex)
          theArray[changedIndex] = newval;
      });
      this.setState({data: newState})
}
```

at line **this.setState({data: newState})** i am getting the error **"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."**

can someone let me know what am i doing wrong and how to fix this issue or update the state without calling the backend service again.

Answer (score 0):

```
replaceStateObject(oldval, newval){
      // var newState = this.state.data;
      let changedIndex = oldval['tableData']['id']
      /* newState.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
        if(index == changedIndex)
          theArray[changedIndex] = newval;
      });*/
      let newState = this.state.data.map((item,index) =>{
        if(index === changedIndex) return newval;
        return item;
      });
      this.setState({data: newState})
}
```

Try to use `map()` instead of `forEach()`

Comment: Hi 
even the map is also not working
i think the issue is with this.setState() that is not allowing to update the data to new value stored in newState

Comment: @user1608906 I think you should add more information about your question. ex) what is newval?